# Solve ITMS-90683 and ITMS-90078 in Info.plist for a Flutter App even though access is not needed

Tags: ios, flutter

After successfully uploading my app to Appstore Connect I got an Email for 2 items: `ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist` and `ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement` even though I don't have any requirements to access Camera from the App I am not sure why it is asked to add a description as per several other Answers on Stackoverflow . The application does not also require any Notification to users so same issue.

In my Info.plist

[image]

My question: **How to fix this issue so that the app can appear on the TestFlight?**

Comment: Maybe you are including a plugin that includes code that is making Apple think you are using the camera or notifications.  You might just add the required purpose strings, but you could have that string say that your app doesn't use the camera or notifications.

Comment: @JohnWeidner where do I add these strings?

Comment: in the same Info.plist file .... you can follow here  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/protected_resources for the keys and values to add.

Comment: Try and avoid using permissions you don’t require as you need to explain the requirement during reviews in Stores :) Maybe find another package or try w/o a package if possible!

Comment: Could you show us the packages you've been using in the pubspec.yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement
```

Open `xcode`, go to `Signing & Capabilities` and click on `Capability` and add `push notification`

it should appear like this
[image]

```
ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist
```

in your flutter project
go to iOS folder -> `Runner` -> `Info.plist`

add this
after "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"

```
 <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
 <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
 <false/>
```